# How can I print to DjVu file as we do create PDF?

Tags: pdf, djvu

How can I print to DjVu file as we do create PDF using 'print' menu item of the programs?

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout this script by Novell:

http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/18551.html